# Compare integer var to an array and take highest value

Tags: jquery, arrays, comparison

I'm searching for a way to compare a value (which is an integer) to an array, and take only the cell which is higher than my value.

For exemple :

```
var array_score_specs = ["17", "24", "33", "46", "68", "128"];
var valeurtest = 0;
for(count=0; count <= parseInt(Object.keys(offers.responseJSON.linux).length); count++){
    if(score_specs < array_score_specs[count]){
        valeurtest = array_score_specs[parseInt(count + 1)];
    }
}
console.log(valeurtest);
```

if score_specs is equel to 25, it should print me "33" in my console ?

I really don't know how to do it and I know it must be pretty simple :(

Thank you in advance for any help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First issue:

```
 parseInt(Object.keys(offers.responseJSON.linux).length)
```

change that with:

```
array_score_specs.length
```

In order to convert a string to number prefix with plus sign and use break to exit the for loop:

```js
var score_specs = 25;
var array_score_specs = ["17", "24", "33", "46", "68", "128"];
var valeurtest = 0;
for(count=0; count <= array_score_specs.length; count++){
    if(score_specs < +array_score_specs[count]){
        valeurtest = array_score_specs[count];
        break;
    }
}
console.log(valeurtest);
```

Comment: Alright, I changed to parseInt.. to array_score_specs.length just after posting while I was checking to fix. By the way it's working, thank you !

Answer (score 1):

you need something like this

```
var array_score_specs = ["17", "24", "33", "46", "68", "128"];
var valeurtest = 0;
for(count=0; count <= array_score_specs.length; count++){
   if(valeurtest < array_score_specs[count]){
      valeurtest = array_score_specs[count + 1];
   }
}
```

console.log(valeurtest);

Hope this helps!